# Realtime Blog Update using django channels means when database changes , the changes reflects on webpage in realtime

Tags: python, django, django-channels, channel

I read the channels documentation and do some practice on `django channels`. It's easy to do chat server using channels. But i want to know about the process how can I update my webpage without refresh when database changes with channels.

How can I send a request to change on database and show on webpage in realtime using channels.

I already tried to understand channels concept and I tried to make simple chat server. Now I want to know about realtime database update and show on webpage.

thank you